# How to implement the interaction among abstract and inherited classes?

Tags: java, methods, overriding, abstract

I have to implement the interaction among the abstract and inherited classes, using `@Override` methods. The thing is that I don't know how to do it, here is my task:

I create an abstract class Account with 3 methods (`pay(int amount)`, `transfer(Account account, int amount)`, `addMoney(int amount)`). Payment must look like an ordinary deduction. I override the methods. Each must have a balance. I **cannot** pay from the `SavingsAccount`, only transfer and add. It also **cannot** go down to negative. `CreditAccount` **cannot** have a positive balance - if I pay form it, it goes down to negative, to return 0, I need to add it. `CheckingAccount` implements all these methods, but **cannot** go down to negative.

I have to create 3 Account-type variables and give them 3 different account types. Here comes the code:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected int amount;
    protected int balance;

    public Account(int amount, int balance) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    void pay(int amount) {
    }

    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
    }

    void addMoney(int amount) {
    }
}

public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
    public CheckingAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        super.pay(amount);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        super.transfer(account, amount);
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        super.addMoney(amount);
    }
}
public class CreditAccount extends Account {
    public CreditAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        super.pay(amount);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        super.transfer(account, amount);
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        super.addMoney(amount);
    }
}

public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
    public SavingsAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        super.addMoney(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still dont understand the problem

Comment: This is a bad class design (“[interface bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_bloat)” and violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). Since your specific account types do not implement the contract imposed by `Account`, they shouldn’t extend that base class. There are several ways of fixing this — probably the simplest would be to have separate multiple “traits” interfaces and let each class implement those traits that it supports.

Comment: agree with conrad, Better would be to divide in three interfaces. Transferrable, Payable, Addable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph and AbhirojPanwar are you guys only trying to fix his structure? or did you understand the question? if you do please help us understand, I can see the class structure may be lacking but the question was never addressed, or was it?

Comment: What is `amount` member is used for?

Comment: @White_King i don't know how to perform my conditions, so that my methods would work! I don't know how to fill them, override correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that base class has to implement some common functionality and it does not have any abstract methods.  So it is marked as abstract to avoid instantiation.

Also it seems that no validation is defined at the account level (whether amount should be positive or not).

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected int amount;
    protected int balance;

    public Account(int amount, int balance) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    void pay(int amount) {
        if (amount > 0)
            this.balance -= amount;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount must be positive");
    }

    void transfer(Account recipient, int amount) {
        recipient.addMoney(amount);
        this.balance -= amount;
    }

    void addMoney(int amount) {
        this.balance += amount;
    }
}
```

Then implementation of `CheckingAccount` needs to override methods to validate resulting balance:

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
    public CheckingAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        if (this.balance >= amount) {
            super.pay(amount);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient funds");
        }
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account recipient, int amount) {
        if (this.balance - amount >= 0) {
            super.transfer(recipient, amount);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient funds for transfer from CheckingAccount");
        }
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        if (this.balance + amount >= 0) {
            super.addMoney(amount);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Balance may not be negative for CheckingAccount");
        }
    }
}
```

For `SavingsAccount` `pay` method has to be overridden to throw an exception.
Possibly it would be worth to override `transfer` and `addMoney` to validate the balance similar to `CheckingAccount`.

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
    public SavingsAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This method is not supported for Savings account");
    }
}
```

And the last for `CreditAccount` you may want to check if the balance is not positive, while using default implementation of `pay` (though credit accounts should have a credit limit too):

```
public class CreditAccount extends Account {
    public CreditAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        if (this.balance - amount <= 0) {
            super.transfer(account, amount);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Balance may not be positive for CreditAccount");
        }
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        if (this.balance + amount <= 0) {
            super.addMoney(amount);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Balance may not be positive for CreditAccount");
        }
    }
}
```

This example is a mere attempt to comply with the above-mentioned requirements to implementation.

As such, it does not satisfy Liskov principle mentioned in the comments similar to the initial class design.

Also, runtime exceptions are used in the example for brevity.